# Angular-ui.bootstrap tooltip over an imagemap area

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to put a [tooltip](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip) on an image map area, it looks like its not supported, is there a way of getting it there, too ?

In this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A1PQVvFmWpsFksE800sB?p=preview), the second kitten has a working image map, but no tooltip on it ...

Answer (score 0):

To get a tooltip on your second image in your plunker demo you need to add a # to your usemap (usemap="#test")
and then add an href="#" to your area element.-7N